# Create Oracle Procedure using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am creating procedure using C#

```
str = @"create or replace procedure awad
                        (O_MSG          OUT    VARCHAR2)
                        is
                        begin
                        O_MSG:='Executed Awad';
                        end;
                        ";
store_cmd = new OracleCommand(str, store_con);
store_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

no error in running this from my code but 
The procedure is creating as Invalid and when i compile it in Toad it is showing me the following error

> PROCEDURE 08903.AWAD On line:  1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ""
>   when expecting one of the following:   ( ; is with authid as cluster
>   compress order using compiled   wrapped external deterministic
>   parallel_enable pipelined The symbol "" was ignored.

if i copy the same code and run it in Toad editor its getting Compile without any error

Comment: str = @"create or replace procedure awad
                        (O_MSG          OUT    VARCHAR2)
                        is
                        begin
                        O_MSG:=''Executed Awad'';
                        end;
                        ";  //try this string

Comment: most likely  your SQL command has non-printable characters. Remove unnecessary white space and line breaks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I last used Oracle (although it was like 10 years ago), these errors would often happen because of CRLF in the SQL. Try

```
str = @"create or replace procedure awad
                    (O_MSG          OUT    VARCHAR2)
                    is
                    begin
                    O_MSG:='Executed Awad';
                    end;
                    ".Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

(although I must say that it if this is the issue, it is extremely unimpressive by them not to have fixed this issue in 10+ years).

Comment: Oracle has many such "unimpressive" features but access to patches requires an NDA. The target database may be an old version too

Comment: +1 as the error mentions `""` (there's nothing inside the quotes) and that `(`, `is` or some other keyword is expected. Looks like ORACLE didn't like the `\r` character and chocked without looking at the rest of the lines

Answer (score 0):

You should escape ' (single quote) with '' ( two single quotes). Try this code:

```
str = @"create or replace procedure awad
                        (O_MSG          OUT    VARCHAR2)
                        is
                        begin
                        O_MSG:=''Executed Awad'';
                        end;
                        ";
                store_cmd = new OracleCommand(str, store_con);
                store_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Single quotes don't need escaping in C#.